# Swift4 UITableView: JSON data loading correctly but throwing error on assigning value

Tags: json, swift4

I have some JSON data that looks like this

```
{
"fullName": "John Doe",
"imageUrl": "https://www.example.com/images/about/team/john.jpg",
"titles": [
  "Founder & President",
  "Advisor"
]
},
  {
"fullName": "Jane Doe",
"imageUrl": "https://www.example.com/images/about/team/jane.jpg",
"titles": [
  "Executive Vice President",
  "Director of Advisor Services and Marketing"
]
},
```

The data gets loaded and parses correctly, but when I run the code I get an error. I think it has to do with the titles section having multiple titles and it doesn't know how to display the titles correctly.

Here is my code.

This is the initial structure.

```
import UIKit

class Managers: Codable {
let managers: [Manager]

init (managers: [Manager]) {
    self.managers = managers
}
}

class Manager: Codable {
let imageUrl: String?
let fullName: String?
let titles: [titles]

init(imageUrl: String?, fullName: String?, titles: [titles]) {
    self.imageUrl = imageUrl
    self.fullName = fullName
    self.titles = titles
}

struct titles: Codable {
    let title: String
}
}
```

This is the Management cell that displays the layout of the image, name and title.

```
import UIKit

class ManagementCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageUrl: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var fullNameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titlesLbl: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

This is the view controller

```
import UIKit

class ManagementViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
final let url = URL(string: "Data from above goes here")
private var managers = [Manager]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadJson()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}


func downloadJson() {
    guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print("Something went wrong")
            return
        }
        print("downloaded")
        do
        {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let downloadedManagers = try decoder.decode([Manager].self, from: data)
            self.managers = downloadedManagers
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong after download")
        }
        }.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return managers.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ManagementCell") as? ManagementCell else { return UITableViewCell() }


    cell.fullNameLbl?.text = managers[indexPath.row].fullName
    cell.titlesLbl?.text = managers[indexPath.row].titles

    if let imageURL = URL(string: managers[indexPath.row].imageUrl!) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageUrl.image = image
                    cell.imageUrl.layer.cornerRadius = 60
                    cell.imageUrl.clipsToBounds = true
                    cell.imageUrl.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    cell.imageUrl.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                    cell.imageUrl.layer.borderWidth = 5
                    cell.imageUrl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

This line of code is throwing an error:
    cell.titlesLbl?.text = managers[indexPath.row].titles

error is Cannot assign value of type '[Manager.titles]' to type 'String?'

Does anyone have a workaround for this. I believe that I have to create a separate loop for the titles since it also has an array of options. Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

On a separate note for the image if an image is missing is causes the app to crash. How do I set a generic image if an image in the JSON data isn't present?

Answer (score 0):

Because `managers[indexPath.row].titles` returns an array of `String`s. Peeking into your data, it looks like the first title in that array is the most recent title the manager holds. You can append an index or call `.first` to get that title:

```
cell.titlesLbl?.text = managers[indexPath.row].titles.first?.title

// or
cell.titlesLbl?.text = managers[indexPath.row].titles[0].title

// or to show all past titles, comma separated                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
cell.titlesLbl?.text = managers[indexPath.row].titles
                         .map({ $0.title })
                         .joined(separator: ", ")
```

The difference is that `.first` won't throw an error if the `titles` array is empty. You get a blank label instead. `[0]` will throw a index out of bounds error if your array is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually tried these two options myself and they still throw the error "Cannot assign value of type 'Manager.Titles' to type 'String?'". I need to display both titles as well. I believe the proper way to do this is to create another function that loops through the titles array and grabs both and outputs the data. I'm just not exactly sure how to do so. I have been researching, but haven't found anything similar to my problem yet.

Comment: I forgot to check the `Titles` struct. Edited the answer

Comment: @CodeDifferent, Now if i want to save this self.managers object into core data ? Then what's the way to save without creating a another model object or struct ? i wan to create a same model object , which inherit codable , nsmanageobject or anything , which could be used for both json decoding and save model to core data. What's the best practices ? i want to avoid creating two model (codable and nsobject) , i want to same model object.